# How to reference a locally packaged source file using terraform aws-lambda module

Tags: terraform, terraform-aws-modules

I'm trying to reference an existing source file that I have created using npm pack and build for a lambda module. When I try to use `local_existing_package` I am receiving an error from the lambda module as if it's trying to lookup the source.zip file from an s3 container vs. locally.  This error is generated from the lambda module itself

error:

```
│   12:   s3_key            = var.s3_existing_package != null ? lookup(var.s3_existing_package, "key", null) : (var.store_on_s3 ? var.s3_prefix != null ? format("%s%s", var.s3_prefix, replace(local.archive_filename, "/^.*//", "")) : replace(local.archive_filename, "/^\\.//", "") : null)
│     ├────────────────
│     │ local.archive_filename is null
```

code from the generated lambda module:

```
locals {
  archive_filename    = element(concat(data.external.archive_prepare.*.result.filename, [null]), 0)
  archive_was_missing = element(concat(data.external.archive_prepare.*.result.was_missing, [false]), 0)

  # Use a generated filename to determine when the source code has changed.
  # filename - to get package from local
  filename    = var.local_existing_package != null ? var.local_existing_package : (var.store_on_s3 ? null : local.archive_filename)
  was_missing = var.local_existing_package != null ? !fileexists(var.local_existing_package) : local.archive_was_missing

  # s3_* - to get package from S3
  s3_bucket         = var.s3_existing_package != null ? lookup(var.s3_existing_package, "bucket", null) : (var.store_on_s3 ? var.s3_bucket : null)
  s3_key            = var.s3_existing_package != null ? lookup(var.s3_existing_package, "key", null) : (var.store_on_s3 ? var.s3_prefix != null ? format("%s%s", var.s3_prefix, replace(local.archive_filename, "/^.*//", "")) : replace(local.archive_filename, "/^\\.//", "") : null)
  s3_object_version = var.s3_existing_package != null ? lookup(var.s3_existing_package, "version_id", null) : (var.store_on_s3 ? element(concat(aws_s3_bucket_object.lambda_package.*.version_id, [null]), 0) : null)
```

my module which is referencing ^^ is defined as:

```
module "my_lambda_fn" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/lambda/aws"
  version = "~>2.17.0"

  function_name = "my-api-fn"
  description   = "Function for example"
  handler       = "src/index.handler"
  runtime       = "nodejs14.x"
  timeout       = 10
  memory_size   = 512
  publish       = true
  cloudwatch_logs_retention_in_days = 60
  attach_tracing_policy = true
  tracing_mode          = "Active"
  # using prepackaged zip vs source
  #https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-aws-modules/lambda/aws/latest#lambda-functions-with-existing-package-prebuilt-stored-locally
  # prebuilt packaging
  create_package         = false
  local_existing_package = "${path.module}/../source.zip"


  store_on_s3 = true
  s3_bucket   = module.s3_bucket.s3_bucket_id
```

I've looked at the examples from github on this module and it looks to match what is recommended.

Can anyone provide an example of how to link the source file or point out what I am missing? This is being built using terraform 0.13.4

Comment: Why are you splatting the `data.external.archive_prepare`? It should be returning an object from a JSON string to its `result` exported resource attribute, which seems to be how you are parsing the return. Are you using the `count` meta-argument with 0.13? We need to see the data block to assist further here.

Comment: @MattSchuchard the middle code block is what is generated in the modules directory after init. It is not part of my definition. I put it in there as reference to the error being generated.   I think I see the issue in referencing the s3_bucket in addition to the local_package. Looking at the provider definition it's one or the other.

Answer (score 0):

After digging into the lambda resource and docs the issue was I was referencing a s3 container to upload the packaged code to

```
  store_on_s3 = true
  s3_bucket   = module.s3_bucket.s3_bucket_id
```

When deploying code for the lambda using a local source, aws uploads the code to a private directory that is not accessible to view but accessible to the lambda. Technically this is the natural deployment for lambdas. I was using the module incorrectly thinking I needed to upload the source.zip which was not needed. Removing the s3 reference resolved the issue. The one change I did notice was publishing this way the route to the handler now requires the package name so now the handler path is `source/src/index.handler`